# fatal errors occuring in my line of code in php

Tags: php, html

I've created two object classes: a Student class, and a Dorm class. in the dorm class i created a method called assign_to_dorm which is supposed to count the amount of current occupants in a dorm, if equal or higher to the capacity, it should return false. if lower than the capcity, the method will then add a Student object into the occupants array property of the Dorm class.

Here is my Dorm class

```
<?php

    class Dorm
    {
        private $dorm_name;
        private $capacity;
        private $occupants = array();

       public function assign_to_dorm($student)
        {
           $ammount = count($this->occupants);

           if($ammount >= $this->capacity)
           {
                return FALSE;
           }else{
               array_push($occupants, $student);
           }
        }

       public function set_dorm_name($dorm_name)
        {
            $this->dorm_name = $dorm_name;
        }

        public function set_capacity($capacity)
        {
            $this->capacity = $capacity;
        }

        public function get_dorm_name()
        {
            return $this->dorm_name;
        }

        public function get_capacity()
        {
            return $this->capacity;
        }

        public function view_occupants()
        {
            foreach($this->occupants as $resident)
              {
                    echo "<br/>" . $resident;
              }
        }

        public function __construct($dorm_name,$capacity)
        {
            $this->set_dorm_name($dorm_name);
            $this->set_capacity($capacity);
        }  
    }
?>
```

In my index file of the website, i created a $dorms array and a $students array that i would be using to test out the method. i then shuffled the list of students and finally i put the students through a loop thus they can be added to a random dorm using the assign_to_dorm() method. afterwards i want it to print out the occupants in the dorm.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Assignment 3</title>
    </head>


    <body>
        <?php

            require('student.php');
            require('dorm.php');


            $dorms = array();
            $dorms[] = new Dorm("Lindo Hall", 50);
            $dorms[] = new Dorm("Smith Hall", 20);
            $dorms[] = new Dorm("Salley Hall", 200);

            $students = array();
            $students[] = new Student("Mike", "Lindo", "Senior", "Male");
            $students[] = new Student("Miguel", "Pakesh", "Freshman", "Male");
            $students[] = new Student("Sammie", "Maxwell", "Sophomore", "Female");
            $students[] = new Student("John", "Smith", "Junior", "Male");
            $students[] = new Student("Jane", "Doe", "Sophomore", "Female");
            $students[] = new Student("John", "Smith", "Senior", "Male");
            $students[] = new Student("Jane", "Doe", "Junior", "Female");
            $students[] = new Student("John", "Smith", "Freshman", "Male");
            $students[] = new Student("Jane", "Doe", "Freshman", "Female");
            $students[] = new Student("John", "Smith", "Sophomore", "Male");
            $students[] = new Student("Jane", "Doe", "Senior", "Female");
            $students[] = new Student("Chris", "Doe", "Freshman", "Male");
            $students[] = new Student("Sarah", "Smith", "Sophomore", "Female");
            $students[] = new Student("Chris", "Doe", "Junior", "Male");
            $students[] = new Student("Sarah", "Smith", "Senior", "Female");

            shuffle($students);

            foreach($students as $student)
            {

                 $dorm =& array_rand($dorms);          // LINE 47
                 $dorm->assign_to_dorm($student);      // LINE 48

            }

            echo "<table><tbody>";

            foreach($dorms as $dorm)
            {
                echo "<tr>";

                echo "<td>" . $dorm->view_occupants() . "</td>";

                echo "</tr>";
            }

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

i keep receiving these error everytime i run the site:

Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.0\www\assignment3\index.php on line 47

Fatal error: Call to a member function assign_to_dorm() on a non-object in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.0\www\assignment3\index.php on line 48

any ideas what i might be doing wrong? i guess there must be something wrong with the code in the assign_to_dorm() method, or maybe i still need a constructor for the occupants array which i dont think is the problem. any help is greatly appreciated. much love

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: the student class only includes 4 private properties (first name, last name, level, gender), its getters and setters, and constructors for all properties.

Answer (score 3):

Modern PHP versions default to returnin objects as references, so the `=&` assignment is not necesasry. That's the first warning.

Second warning: array_rand returns an array KEY, not an array VALUE. So you're getting back something like `5`, not the 5th object you assigned to the array.

The code should be

```
$dorm_index = array_rand($dorms);          // LINE 47
$dorms[$dorm_index]->assign_to_dorm($student);      // LINE 48
```

Answer (score 2):

from http://php.net/array_rand

```
mixed array_rand ( array $input [, int $num_req = 1 ] )

Picks one or more random entries out of an array, and returns
the key (or keys) of the random entries.
```

it picks the key... you need to say

```
$key = array_rand($dorms);

$dorm = $dorms[$key];
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_Rand` doesnt return the element, it returns the key. You need to then get the element:

```
$key = array_rand($dorms);          // LINE 47
$dorm = $dorms[$key];
$dorm->assign_to_dorm($student);
```

Comment: that worked! thanks so much, now all i keep getting is this error for the line of code in the Dorm class

Comment: Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.0\www\assignment3\dorm.php on line 23

Comment: public function assign_to_dorm($student)
        {
           $ammount = count($this->occupants);

           if($ammount >= $this->capacity)
           {
                return FALSE;
           }else{
               array_push($occupants, $student);
           }
        }

Comment: your forgot the the `$this->` on your occupants in the array_push call.